# SQL While Loop Insert with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a SQL While loop that will update a temp table with values from another table. Values from the other table:

```
477286
560565
499330
391827
127375
526354
501736
357359
410433
500946
261297
377667
135931
235691
247239
143672
548752
471945
...
```

Wrote the following, however, it only inserts the last value multiple times over.

Here is the code:

```
USE Reports
GO
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable (CreatedByID int, LastUpdatedByID int, ID int, 
AlertDE int, Alert char(50), StartDTTM datetime, EndDTTM datetime, 
IsInactiveFLAG char(1),AlertDetails char(1));
    DECLARE @numrows INT
    SELECT @numrows  = COUNT(*) FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Eligible]
    DECLARE @id int 
    DECLARE @LoopCount INT = 1
    DECLARE @count int = @numrows
    SELECT  @id = [id] FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Eligible]
WHILE (@LoopCount <= @count)
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO #TempTable (CreatedByID, LastUpdatedByID, ID, AlertDE, Alert, StartDTTM, EndDTTM, IsInactiveFLAG,AlertDetails) 
    VALUES (52,52,@id,0,'Eligible',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 
00:00:00.000','N','') 
    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
END 
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

I am assuming I have to tell it to loop through the values in the other table somehow but I am not positive if that is the right approach or if in general I am taking the long way around the bus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why are you using a loop?  You can do this with an `insert . . . select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (CreatedByID, LastUpdatedByID, ID, AlertDE, Alert, StartDTTM, EndDTTM, IsInactiveFLAG, AlertDetails) 
    SELECT 52, 52, e.id, 0, 'Eligible', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'N', ''
    FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Eligible] e ;
```

See eg https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp for more info.

Comment: Thus me mentioning the "long way around the bus" LOL! This reminds me of the time my friend showed me that the arrow on the gas gauge indicates which side of the car the gas cap is on.

Comment: @GMR ... I'm surprised you unaccepted the answer.  Is there a reason?

Comment: I found my way here because my DB has triggers that don't allow multiple rows to be inserted at a time.

Answer (score 1):

GMR, I found a way to accomplish my need which is similar to yours. Hopefully this will help you too.

```
DECLARE
  @LoopId  int
 ,@TheOrderNumber  varchar(20)

DECLARE @CheckThisItem TABLE
 (
   LoopId  int  not null  identity(1,1)
  ,TheOrderNumber varchar(20)  not null
 )

INSERT @CheckThisItem 
SELECT Order_Number AS TheOrderNumber
FROM [dbo].[Table_Storing_Order_Number] ORDER BY Order_Number ASC
SET @LoopId = @@rowcount
WHILE @LoopId > 0
   BEGIN  
     SELECT @TheOrderNumber = TheOrderNumber
     FROM @CheckThisItem
     WHERE LoopId = @LoopId
-- Start inserting record pulled for while loop
        INSERT [dbo].[The_Destination_Table]
            SELECT TOP (1)
            A, B, C, D
            FROM [dbo].[Source_Table] ST
            WHERE 
            ST.Order_Number = @TheOrderNumber
        -- Set number to reduce loop counter
    SET @LoopId = @LoopId - 1
 END;
```